# check char array against a different array vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

I'm trying to check if what the user entered is in the letter array. And then translate the letter to morse code which is the Morse array. I had to use a char array to display the user input in order but it displays the morse code in alphabetical order. How do I stop display it correctly? Thanks in advance.

```
    Dim strCode As String = txtCode.Text.ToUpper 'What the user enters must be letters it can also be - or =
    Dim strText() As Char = strCode.ToCharArray

    Dim strLetter() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
    Dim strMorse() As String = {"*=", "=***", "=*=*", "=**", "*", "**=*", "==*", "****", "**", "*===", "=*=", "*=**", "==", "=*", "===", "*==*", "==*=", "*=*", "***", "=", "**=", "***=", "*==", "=**=", "=*==", "==**"}

    For Each letter As Char In strText
        For x As Integer = 0 To strLetter.Length - 1
            If strCode.Contains(strLetter(x)) Then
                MessageBox.Show(strMorse(x))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a dictionary and iterate through all the characters in a string and you won't have to worry about finding characters and translating them in the correct order. Use the alphabet letter as the key, and the morse code as the value...then you can just go through the text and translate each letter like this:

```
    Dim translate As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{" ", " "}, _
                                                             {"A", "*="}, _
                                                             {"B", "=***"}, _
                                                             {"C", "=*=*"}, _
                                                             {"D", "=**"}, _
                                                             {"E", "*"}, _
                                                             {"F", "**=*"}, _
                                                             {"G", "==*"}, _
                                                             {"H", "****"}, _
                                                             {"I", "**"}, _
                                                             {"J", "*==="}, _
                                                             {"K", "=*="}, _
                                                             {"L", "*=**"}, _
                                                             {"M", "=="}, _
                                                             {"N", "=*"}, _
                                                             {"O", "==="}, _
                                                             {"P", "*==*"}, _
                                                             {"Q", "==*="}, _
                                                             {"R", "*=*"}, _
                                                             {"S", "***"}, _
                                                             {"T", "="}, _
                                                             {"U", "**="}, _
                                                             {"V", "***="}, _
                                                             {"W", "*=="}, _
                                                             {"X", "=**="}, _
                                                             {"Y", "=*=="}, _
                                                             {"Z", "==**"}}
    Dim translatedMsg As String = Nothing
    For Each c As Char In txtCode.Text.ToUpper
        translatedMsg += translate(c) & " "
    Next
    Debug.Print(translatedMsg.TrimEnd)

    'Output for "Hello World": **** * *=** *=** ===   *== === *=* *=** =**
```

---

**Edit:** Well, going backwards from a value to its key isn't as clean as going from key to value because there's no native function for it, but Linq works just fine for that...and if I'm honest, I didn't think about the spaces translating back at first. I would maybe add a special character to the dictionary for spaces, and that would make the translation a lot easier. But nonetheless, I'll stick with my first example for example's sake, and here's how you would translate the message back. I used "Hello World" again, and to get around the spaces problem, I just substituted an underscore for the space so I could decode the message properly (Also, obviously you lose upper/lowercase distinction since morse code doesn't distinguish between the two):

```
    Dim strMorseMsg As String = "**** * *=** *=** ===   *== === *=* *=** =**"

    strMorseMsg = strMorseMsg.Replace("   ", " _ ") 'substitution here to distinguish spaces between words from the space between letters
    Dim aryMorseMsg() As String = strMorseMsg.Split(CChar(" "))

    Dim originalMessage As String = Nothing
    For Each code As String In aryMorseMsg
        If code.Equals("_") Then 'here's where the underscore helps branch our logic between adding a space and adding a letter
            originalMessage += " "
        Else
            originalMessage += translate.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Value = code).Key
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(originalMessage)

    'Outputs "HELLO WORLD"
```

Comment: Nice solution, that's exactly what a dictionary is for. Note that you'll need spaces between the letters as well. Otherwise, the recipient won't know whether `***` means `EEE`, `EI`, `IE` or `S`.

Comment: @Heinzi I second that! With a dictionary, I can easily tell what the point of the code is and immediately know how to check the translation if I feel the need.

Comment: where should i add the spaces so that it recognizes *** as "S" for example?

Comment: How can i go from morse code to letters because if loop through char it checks each character individually.

Comment: Did you even look at the edit? It isn't looping through chars, it splits the message into groups of chars and iterates through the groups.

Comment: First i asked the other question before i saw the new version and second that makes sense but is hard to integrate into the code i already have so instead i checked each word by splitting them at the space.

Answer (score 2):

If you step through your code using something simple, such as "BA", you can see the logic error. You are never comparing the letter in the outer loop to anything in the inner one. Instead, your If statement is asking "hey, does my input contain the first letter in my `strLetter` array?" Yep, "A" is in there (even though it isn't the first character).

A much simpler solution to the assignment would use the offset of the letter's ASCII value from "A" if the letter is within range (between A and Z). This removes the need to define `strLetter`. You can also omit the conversion of the input text into a character array. A string already lets you enumerate the characters.

```
Dim strCode As String = txtCode.Text.ToUpper 'What the user enters must be letters it can also be - or =

Dim strMorse() As String = {"*=", "=***", "=*=*", "=**", "*", "**=*", "==*", "****", "**", "*===", "=*=", "*=**", "==", "=*", "===", "*==*", "==*=", "*=*", "***", "=", "**=", "***=", "*==", "=**=", "=*==", "==**"}

For Each letter As Char In strCode
  If letter >' "A"c AndAlso letter <= "Z"c Then
    MessageBox.Show(strMorse(AscW(letter) - AscW("A"c)))
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Still new to all this so the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim codes() As String = { _
        "*=", "=***", "=*=*", "=**", "*", "**=*", "==*", "****", "**", _
        "*===", "=*=", "*=**", "==", "=*", "===", "*==*", "==*=", "*=*", _
        "***", "=", "**=", "***=", "*==", "=**=", "=*==", "==**" _
    }

    Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()

    ' Convert characters to values that can be used as indexes in the code array
    Dim indexes = input.[Select](Of Integer)(Function(l As Char) Asc(l) - 65)
    ' limit the values to based on the range of possible values
    Dim boundsCheck = indexes.Where(Function(l As Integer) l >= 0 And l <= 26)
    ' map the valid inputs to codes fro myour array
    Dim outCodes = boundsCheck.[Select](Of String)(Function(l As Integer) codes(l))
    ' concatenate the codes into a string and display 
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", outCodes))
End Sub
```